# Floating Div returns to next row

Tags: css, html, fluid-layout

Why are my fluid divs spazzing out?

http://jsfiddle.net/NF2T2/

Thanks for any help!

Sorry i'm pretty new to CSS/HTML..

Comment: there's some extra css in there please ignore it

Comment: It would save us time if you eliminated it on your fiddle.

Comment: @JoeTitterton - you should only be providing a "test case". That is, remove all the code that you use for your project, and leave only the code that applies to your problem.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SineMetu/9vuGz/ Yeah sorry bout that the new fiddle contains only the relevant code

Answer (score 1):

Probably your calculation is wrong.

Taking out the margin by setting it to zero aligned the div properly. Which means your percentages did not add up to 100%

```
#div_left{
   float:left;
   width:48%;
   margin-left:0;  //this was 3.6%
   height:auto;
}
```

Comment: I wanted some spacing between the divs, I orginaly had a margin of 4% which added up to 100% exactly (since both div widths were at 48%), but that caused the right div to return. When I changed it to to 3.6 the right div fit on the page, but when I proceeded to shrink the page it returned. The container the divs lie in has a width of 100%. Both the divs combined take up 96%, with a margin between of 4%. (Thats how I want it to look)

Comment: Are the 1px borders messing it up?

Comment: You just need to measure everything and make sure they equal or less than 100% e.g. `margin + padding + div_size = 100%`

Comment: @JoeTitterton, Yes the border also counts to the `div` size. So the total width/height of an element will be `padding + border + width/height`. Add that the `margin` and that should be a total of `100%`. Installing Firebug for Firefox will help you understand more about the size of elements and styling as well. Also I noticed that the HTML in your jsFiddle is not correct. You forgot to close some `p` tags and have extra closing `div` tags.

Comment: Ok, apparently I needed to add a div just for the borders. 

.borders{
    border:1px;
}